# Flutter full screen splash in Android (native)

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen, launch-screen

I'm tried to make a fullscreen splash (with a background image) in Flutter Android (in iOS everything seem easier).

But in default launch background, the bitmap tag seem not to be cover the height and width, i tried gravity attributes: fill, fill_vertical, fill_horizontal, ... but the result not as expected, when i use "fill_vertical" the width is shrinking a bit although the height is correct, the "center" is not full screen.

In gravity center:

[image: In gravity center]

In fill_vertical
[image]

What I'm expected

[image]

I think "bitmap" can not cover with keep ratio image.

file launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/splash_color"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: post your code here as well and the image

Comment: @Quicklearner Okay, I just add the code

Comment: Hope the help ...

Comment: There are some steps requires to do so. I recommend you go through the official documentation once. Link: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen

Answer (score 0):

The way Android launch screen works is the background drawable is stretched to fit the screen and the logo - usually the second item in the `layer-list` is centered. What you can do here as a workaround is separate the background of the image with the foreground character.